# Creating a table using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to front-end web development and right now I am working on a test task to create a table using javascript.Here is my html file:

```
<title>Pixel Art Maker!</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Monoton">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"> </head> <body>
<h1>Lab: Pixel Art Maker</h1>

<h2>Choose Grid Size</h2>
<form id="sizePicker">
    Grid Height:
    <input type="number" id="inputHeight" name="height" min="1" value="1">
    Grid Width:
    <input type="number" id="inputWeight" name="width" min="1" value="1">
    <input type="submit" onclick="makeGrid()">
</form>

<h2>Pick A Color</h2>
<input type="color" id="colorPicker">

<h2>Design Canvas</h2>
<table id="pixelCanvas"></table>

<script src="designs.js"></script> </body> </html>
```

And my javascript file:

```
function makeGrid() {


var rows=inputHeight; var cols=inputWeight; //Referencw for the body var body=document.getElementsbyTagName("body")[0];

//create a table element and a <tbody> element var table1=document.createElement("table"); var tableBody=document.createElement("tbody");

//creating cells for (var i=0;i<rows;i++){  //creating a table row  var R=document.createElement("tr");     for(var j=0;j<cols;j++){        //create a table data element       var C=document.createElement("td");         R.appendchild(C);


    }   //adding the row to the end of the table body
     tableBody.appendChild(R); } //putting the <tbody> in the <table> table1.appendChild(tableBody); //appending <table> into <body> body.appendChild(table1);

}
```

I am supposed to get user input of rows and columns via submit button and generate a table according to that specification.So far my attmepts are unsuccessful,more precisely when I hit submit,nothing happens and the values revert back to "1".

I would really appreciate your guidance and feedback.

Comment: Simply assigning an input an id is not enough, you need to reference the DOM object's value by using document.getElementById("inputHeight").value

Comment: `var rows = inputHeight;` <<< do you notice anything strange here?

Comment: @Roko C.Buljan: as I said I am new to front-end development.

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't need a `<form>`. There's nothing to submit to.
2. Use `document.getElementById`
3. You already have a `<table id>` in HTML. Reference it!
4. You don't need therefore a `document.body` reference.
5. To retrieve the integer use `parseInt( number, radix )` since input `value` is a String
6. Clear your table from existing content before appending new stuff.
7. Use `addEventListener(EventName, callback)` instead of inline JavaScript (`onclick`)
8. *Weight* is not **Width**!

```js
function makeGrid() {

  var ELTable       = document.getElementById("pixelCanvas"); // You already have it!
  var ELInputHeight = document.getElementById("inputHeight");
  var ELInputWidth  = document.getElementById("inputWidth");
  var rows = parseInt(ELInputHeight.value, 10);
  var cols = parseInt(ELInputWidth.value, 10);  // Weight? you mean Width!

  ELTable.innerHTML = ""; // Empty table before inserting new stuff

  var tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
  
  for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {           // N rows...
    var R = document.createElement("tr");    // Make row.
    for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {         // N cells...
      var C = document.createElement("td");  // Make cell.
      R.appendChild(C);                      // Insert cell into row.
    }
    tbody.appendChild(R);                    // Insert row into tbody
  }
  
  ELTable.appendChild(tbody);                // Insert tbody into table
}

document.getElementById("makeGrid").addEventListener("click", makeGrid);
```

```css
td { padding:10px; background:#000; }
```

```html
Height: <input type="number" id="inputHeight" min="1" value="1"> 
Width: <input type="number" id="inputWidth" min="1" value="1">
<button id="makeGrid">MAKE</button>
<br>
Color: <input type="color" id="colorPicker">
<table id="pixelCanvas"></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I create function for generate body of table, and listener for butto

```js
function createTableBody(height, width) {
    let tr = document.createElement('tr');
    let td = document.createElement('td');
    let docFr = new DocumentFragment();
    for (let i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        tr.append(td.cloneNode());
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        docFr.append(tr.cloneNode(true));
    }
    return docFr;

}
let table = document.getElementById('pixelCanvas');
let createTableButton = document.getElementById('createTableButton');
let inputHeight = document.getElementById('inputHeight');

let inputWidth = document.getElementById('inputWeight');
createTableButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let parentTable = table.parentNode;
    let tableClone = table.cloneNode();
    parentTable.replaceChild(tableClone, table);//clear old table
    table = tableClone; 
    tableClone.append(createTableBody(inputHeight.value, inputWidth.value));
    // if you need , you can add ajax request 
    console.log(table)
});
```

```html
<title>Pixel Art Maker!</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Monoton">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"> </head> <body>
<h1>Lab: Pixel Art Maker</h1>

<h2>Choose Grid Size</h2>
    Grid Height:
    <input type="number" id="inputHeight" name="height" min="1" value="1">
    Grid Width:
    <input type="number" id="inputWeight" name="width" min="1" value="1">
    <input type="button"  id="createTableButton">
<h2>Pick A Color</h2>
<input type="color" id="colorPicker">

<h2>Design Canvas</h2>
<table id="pixelCanvas"></table>
 </body> </html>
```

If you need send  data to server, you can use ajax, and i replace your `submit` to `button`, remove `form`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<form id="form-grid" method="post" onsubmit="makeGrid()">
    <h2 id="grid-size">Choose Grid Size</h2>
    <label for="inputHeight">Grid height:</label>
    <input type="number" id="inputHeight" name="height" min="1" value="1" aria-describedby="grid-size" />

    <label for="inputWeight">Grid width:</label>
    <input type="number" id="inputWeight" name="width" min="1" value="1" aria-describedby="grid-size" />

    <h2>Pick a color</h2>
    <label for="colorPicker">Color:</label>
    <input type="color" id="colorPicker" name="color" />

    <input type="submit" value="Make Grid" />
</form>

<div id="pixelCanvas"></div>
```

Do note the addition of explicit `label`'s here. These are important for accessibility!

I've added a submit handler to the form, and removed it from the button. I find it's a bit cleaner, but your approach would ultimately work too.

Then in your `designs.js` file, you might have:

```
function makeGrid(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // prevents the form from submitting

    var form = document.querySelector('#form-grid');
    var rows = form.querySelector('#inputHeight').value;
    var cols = form.querySelector('#inputWeight').value;
    var wrapper = document.querySelector('#pixelCanvas');

    var table = document.createElement('table');

    for (var r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
        var tr = table.insertRow();
        for (var c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
            var td = tr.insertCell();
        }
    }

    wrapper.appendChild(table);
}
```

A few reminders:

- Use `label` to associate a form field with it's visible label. This is necessary for assistive technology such as screen readers.
- Consider a `fieldset` to group all of the options, increasing its accessibility.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

As @Katamari said, it looks like you're not properly accessing the elements and getting their values.

To access an element, you can use [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and pass in a CSS selector.

```
var rowInput = document.querySelector("#inputHeight");
var colInput = document.querySelector("#inputWidth");
```

Since you have assigned IDs, you could use [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

```
var rowInput = document.getElementById("inputHeight");
var colInput = document.getElementById("inputWidth");
```

Either way, you'll get an element or `null` if the element can't be found. Once you have the element, just get the `value` property to get the user results.

```
var rows = rowInput.value;
var cols = colInput.value;
```

If you want to avoid error that could be caused by not finding the element, you can check for the element before referencing the value.

```
var rows = 1;
var cols = 1;

if (rowInput) {
    rows = rowInput.value;
}

if (colInput) {
    cols = colInput.value;
}
```

This can be converted into a single line using a [tenary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

```
var rows = rowInput
    ? rowInput.value
    : 1;
var cols = colInput
    ? colInput.value
    : 1;
```

Comment: I disagree with the use of ternary operators here. You wouldn't have a table with zero rows or zero cells. The OP is defaulting to `1`, which is best.

Comment: That's a fair point, I missed that. That would also work against the logical operators - I'll edit the answer